# how to show column difference in rows which we get in inner join of two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two database db1 and db2. Both having auth_item table, I have Taken Inner join of this two database auth_item table with t1.name = t2.name column. 
Now i want to compare all columns of these two tables and show result of different column values with inner join.

t1 from db1

```
-----------------  
:name   : type  :
----------------- 
: abc   : 1     : 
:  xy   : 2     :  
:  as   : 3     : 
:  yz   : 2     :  
-----------------
```

t2 from  db2

```
-----------------  
:name   : type  :  
-----------------  
: abc   : 2     :   
:  xy   : 2     :   
:  as   : 3     :  
-----------------
```

In Inner Joint Of t1 and t2 where t1.name = t2.name it will show

```
-----------------  
:name   : type  :  
-----------------  
: abc   : 1     :   
:  xy   : 2     :   
:  as   : 3     :  
-----------------
```

but I want to show column difference output as

```
-----------------  
:name   : type  :  
-----------------  
: abc   : 1     :   
-----------------
```

So please suggest Query for this..

Comment: The dataset is inadequately representative of the problem. Types 11,12, and 13 would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select a.name, a.type from t1 inner join
t2 on t1.name = t2.name
where a.type!=b.type
```

Comment: This one is not working.  Actually my table has more column and i want to compare all of them. These one is just demo table.